# Creating an Dynamic Template in Mail gun and express js

Tags: node.js, express, mailgun

is there a way to create an html file and it will dynamically change the variables inside of this html using this two(mailgun and expressjs) like sending an reset password email?  i am new to this so i don't know where to start

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking at generating HTML dynamically, you could try something like [EJS](http://ejs.co/). With that you can create a `welcome-email.ejs` which contains all your HTML for the email, and some special `<%` tags that allow you to insert variables like so:

`<p>Welcome, <%=user.firstName%>!</p>`

```
const ejs = require('ejs')
const mailgun = ...

function sendWelcomeEmail(user) {    
    // arg 1: filepath from root, arg 2: object to pass into EJS template
    ejs.renderFile('server/app/emailTemplates/welcome-email.ejs', {user: user.firstName}, function(err, htmlString) {
        if (err) console.error(err);

        // not sure how mailgun works, but it's probably like this
        let mailOptions = { html: htmlString, to: user.email, ... }

        mailgun.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
            if (err) console.error(err);
        });
    });
};
```